# Django in-memory database model creation failure

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB MEMORY engine. I defined `max_heap_table_size` in `my.cnf`, restarted the database service. Now, I run the migration and get:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Storage engine MEMORY doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns`

My erroneous model is:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    dtype = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    info = models.CharField(max_length=64000)
```

Though, max `VARCHAR` is 65535.What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs state [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/varchar/), `65.535` are actually bytes, which leads to a maximum of 21.844 characters if using `UTF-8`.

> A variable-length string. M represents the maximum column length in
>   characters. The range of M is 0 to 65,535. The effective maximum
>   length of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes,
>   which is shared among all columns) and the character set used. For
>   example, utf8 characters can require up to three bytes per character,
>   so a VARCHAR column that uses the utf8 character set can be declared
>   to be a maximum of 21,844 characters.

Since the [`max_length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.max_length) of a `CharField` in a Django model specifies the length in characters rather than in bytes, I assume this is what causes the error.

Comment: So, what is the best option to store 30-40k unicode symbols in-memory?

Comment: @ka2m I honestly don't know. Considering `MariaDB` it seems like a hard limit. Good question if there is a performant and still convenient workaround. Depending on the use case maybe passing some tasks off to something like `Redis` might also work, but that's of course completely depending on the use case.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "30-40k unicode symbols".  One long string?

Answer (score 0):

Make the table MyISAM or InnoDB.  Either will quickly cache your string, thereby making respond as if it were "in-memory".

As for the confusing error message -- a `VARCHAR` that needs more than 64K *bytes* is silently turned into `MEDIUMTEXT`.

If your string can be broken into multiple pieces, you could have multiple rows.  (Have a second column with a row number of some kind.)